# group_by multiple times in ruby

Tags: ruby, group-by

I have an array of hashes called `events`:

```
events = [
  {:name => "Event 1", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "South", :micro_area => "A"},
  {:name => "Event 2", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "South", :micro_area => "A"},
  {:name => "Event 3", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "South", :micro_area => "B"},
  {:name => "Event 4", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "South", :micro_area => "B"},
  {:name => "Event 5", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "North", :micro_area => "A"},
  {:name => "Event 6", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "North", :micro_area => "A"},
  {:name => "Event 7", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "North", :micro_area => "B"},
  {:name => "Event 8", :date => "2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area => "North", :micro_area => "B"}
]
```

I want to know how to `group_by` first `date`, then `area` then `micro_area` to end up with a single array of hashes for example:

```
[
  {
    "2019-02-21 08:00:00": {
      "South": {
        "A": [
          {:name=>"Event 1", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"South", :micro_area=>"A" },
          {:name=>"Event 2", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"South", :micro_area=>"A" }
        ],
        "B": [
          {:name=>"Event 3", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"South", :micro_area=>"B" },
          {:name=>"Event 4", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"South", :micro_area=>"B" }
        ]  
      },
      "North": {
        "A": [
          {:name=>"Event 5", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"North", :micro_area=>"A" },
          {:name=>"Event 6", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"North", :micro_area=>"A" }
        ],
        "B": [
          {:name=>"Event 7", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"North", :micro_area=>"B" },
          {:name=>"Event 8", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"North", :micro_area=>"B" }
        ]  
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Trying `events.group_by { |r| [r[:date], r[:area], r[:micro_area]] }` doesn't seem too work the way I want it to.

Comment: I've changed the `area` of events 5-8 to `"North"` to match the grouping.

Comment: Thanks for making it more readable :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think following will work for you,

```
events = [
  { name: 'Event 1', date: '2019-02-21 08:00:00', area: 'South', micro_area: 'A' }
]

events.group_by { |x| x[:date] }.transform_values do |v1|
  v1.group_by { |y| y[:area] }.transform_values do |v2|
    v2.group_by { |z| z[:micro_area] }
  end
end
# {
#   "2019-02-21 08:00:00"=>{
#     "South"=>{
#       "A"=>[
#         {:name=>"Event 1", :date=>"2019-02-21 08:00:00", :area=>"South", :micro_area=>"A"}
#       ]
#     }
#   }
# }
```

Comment: I found difficult to put above in `do--end` block which can be much readable.

Comment: Would be awesome if we could put this into a method that takes any number of groups

Comment: I've reformatted the code a bit, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, it is much better now.

Comment: @MikeHolford See my [(gist) comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805207/group-by-multiple-times-in-ruby/54805641#comment96396078_54807139) under the answer of Stefan.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to build the nested structure as you traverse your hash:

```
events.each_with_object({}) do |event, result|
  d, a, m = event.values_at(:date, :area, :micro_area)
  result[d] ||= {}
  result[d][a] ||= {}
  result[d][a][m] ||= []
  result[d][a][m] << event
end
```

Comment: This will take less time as compared to that of my answer +1

Comment: If you need this functionality often you could consider monkey patching *Enumerable*. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/b6a7a0b7a5872a74f1cc4e917e5af53d

Answer (score 4):

Another option is grouping them like you did in the question. Then build the nested structure from the array used as key.

```
# build an endless nested structure
nested = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&hash.default_proc) }

# group by the different criteria and place them in the above nested structure
events.group_by { |event| event.values_at(:date, :area, :micro_area) }
      .each { |(*path, last), events| nested.dig(*path)[last] = events }

# optional - reset all default procs
reset_default_proc = ->(hash) { hash.each_value(&reset_default_proc).default = nil if hash.is_a?(Hash) }
reset_default_proc.call(nested)
```

The above leaves the answer in the `nested` variable.

**References:**

- [`Hash::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) to create the nested hash.
- [`Hash#default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) to get the default proc of a hash.
- [`Hash#default=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D) to reset the hash default back to `nil`.
- [`Hash#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) to traverse the nested structure until the last node.
- [`Hash#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) to set the last node equal to the grouped events.
- [Array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) and [array to argument conversion](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) to capture all but the last node into `path` and call `#dig` with the contents of `path` as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution that will handle arbitrary levels of nesting and arbitrary grouping objects.

```
def hashify(events, grouping_keys)
  return events if grouping_keys.empty?
  first_key, *remaining_keys = grouping_keys
  events.group_by { |h| h[first_key] }.
         transform_values { |a|
           hashify(a.map { |h|
             h.reject { |k,_| k == first_key } },
             remaining_keys) }
end
```

Before executing this with the sample data from the questions let's add a hash with a different date to `events`.

```
events <<
  { :name=>"Event 8", :date=>"2018-12-31 08:00:00",
    :area=>"North",   :micro_area=>"B" }

grouping_keys = [:date, :area, :micro_area]
```

```
hashify(events, grouping_keys)
  #=> {"2019-02-21 08:00:00"=>{
  #      "South"=>{
  #        "A"=>[{:name=>"Event 1"}, {:name=>"Event 2"}],
  #        "B"=>[{:name=>"Event 3"}, {:name=>"Event 4"}]
  #      },
  #      "North"=>{
  #        "A"=>[{:name=>"Event 5"}, {:name=>"Event 6"}],
  #        "B"=>[{:name=>"Event 7"}, {:name=>"Event 8"}]
  #      }
  #    },
  #    "2018-12-31 08:00:00"=>{
  #      "North"=>{
  #        "B"=>[{:name=>"Event 8"}]
  #      }
  #    }
  #  }
```

```
hashify(events, [:date, :area])
  #=> {"2019-02-21 08:00:00"=>{
  #      "South"=>[
  #        {:name=>"Event 1", :micro_area=>"A"},
  #        {:name=>"Event 2", :micro_area=>"A"},
  #        {:name=>"Event 3", :micro_area=>"B"},
  #        {:name=>"Event 4", :micro_area=>"B"}
  #      ],
  #      "North"=>[
  #        {:name=>"Event 5", :micro_area=>"A"},
  #        {:name=>"Event 6", :micro_area=>"A"},
  #        {:name=>"Event 7", :micro_area=>"B"},
  #        {:name=>"Event 8", :micro_area=>"B"}
  #      ]
  #    },
  #    "2018-12-31 08:00:00"=>{
  #      "North"=>[
  #       {:name=>"Event 8", :micro_area=>"B"}
  #      ]
  #    }
  #  }
```

See [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject).